# Converting a HTML object to a string / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

What im trying to archive is to convert an html object into a string. The html object is returning a path to an image, i need the last part of this string which is the name of the image. Then i want to update an html element with the image name. imgObj is an img element.

```
if (imgObj[0] != "") {
    var url = obj.val(value).html(imgObj[1]);
    var index = url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1;
    var imageName = url.substr(index);
    document.getElementById('imageName').innerHTML = imageName;
}
```

How do you convert  an html object to a string?

Comment: *"What im trying to archive is to convert an htnl object into a string."* No, that's not what you're trying to achieve. I suspect you want to get some property from the HTML object, but the question is unclear. What is `imgObj`? Is it an `img` element (`HTMLImageElement`)?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. That is correct, imgObj is a img element.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume `imgObj` is an `HTMLImageElement` (`img` element).

If you're looking for its image path, that's the `src` property, which is a string. To get the last segment of that path, you can use `split`:

```
var segments = imgObj.src.split('/');
if (segments.length) {
    var imageName = segments[segments.length - 1];
    document.getElementById('imageName').innerHTML = imageName;
}
```

But if, say, `imgObj` is an `input` element (`HTMLInputElement`), then you'd want its `value`; only the first line changes:

```
var segments = imgObj.value.split('/');
```